# Python 2.7 RE Search by condition

Tags: python-2.7

When I am using re.search, I have some problem.

For example:

```
a = '<span class="chapternum">1 </span>abc，def.</span>'
```

How can I search the number '1'?
Or how to search by matching digit start with ">" and end with writespace?

I tried:

```
test = re.search('(^>)(\d+)(\s$)', a)
print test
>> []
```

It is fail to get the number "1"

Comment: Example: a = <span class="chapternum">1 </span>abc，def.</span>

Comment: Have you considered using an actual HTML parser? Using regex is [notoriously unwise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761).

Comment: As funny as the answer ( @jonrsharpe linked) may have been, I will never forget it.  Do not use regex to parse html, ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` and `$` indicate the beginning and the end of the string. If you get rid of them you have your answer:

```
>>> test = re.search('(>)(\d+)(\s)', a)
>>> test.groups()
('>', '1', ' ')
```

Not sure that you need the first and last groups though (capturing with parenthesis):

```
>>> a = '<span class="chapternum">23 </span>abc，def.</span>' 
>>> test = re.search('>(\d+)\s', a)
>>> test.group(1)
'23'
```

Comment: Thanks for your quickly response. Although this can find out '1', I can't sure that all the digit will match group(1) in my hold program. Therefore, I am seeking a way to search only the result that like this pattern: >\d+\s.

Comment: `test.group(1)` means 'the first group', the `\d+` part captures all digits.

Comment: Oh. I got it. Thanks a lot.